# Simple way to read local file using Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to learn the new Swift programming language. It looks great, but I'm having a difficult time doing something as simple as reading the content of a local .txt file.

I have tried the few examples I could find through Google, but they give compile errors, like this answer here: [Read and write data from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file)
If I tweak the code a bit, it works, but can only read from a special location within the project.

Why isn't it just as simple to read a .txt file with Swift as it is with for instance Ruby? And how would I go about reading the content of a file located at `~/file.txt`?

Thnx

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you have a tilde in your path you can try this:

```
let location = "~/file.txt".stringByExpandingTildeInPath
let fileContent = NSString(contentsOfFile: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

otherwise just use this:

```
let location = "/Users/you/Desktop/test.txt"
let fileContent = NSString(contentsOfFile: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

This gives you a string representation of the file, which I assumed is what you want.
You can use `NSData(contentsOfFile: location)` to get a binary representation, but you would normally do that for, say, music files and not a text file.

*Update: With Xcode 7 and Swift 2 this doesn't work anymore. You can now use*

```
let location = NSString(string:"~/file.txt").stringByExpandingTildeInPath
let fileContent = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: I got this error: `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSString' with an argument list of type '(contentsOfFile: String, encoding: Ulnt, error: NilLiteralConvertible)'

Comment: let location = NSString(string:"/Users/you/Desktop/myCSVfile.csv")
        let fileContent = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: location as String, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

Answer (score 18):

```
    let file = "/Users/user/Documents/text.txt"
    let path=URL(fileURLWithPath: file)
    let text=try? String(contentsOf: path)
```

Comment: This deserves way more +1. simple, clean, and no need for NS. Am I missing something? Someone enlighten me if this is flawed?

Answer (score 16):

This would work:

```
let path = "~/file.txt"
let expandedPath = path.stringByExpandingTildeInPath
let data: NSData? = NSData(contentsOfFile: expandedPath)

if let fileData = data {
    let content = NSString(data: fileData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
}
```

Note that `data` may be nil, so you should check for that.

EDIT:
Don't forget conditional unwrapping - looks much nicer ;)

Comment: I don't get the "if let fileData = data" part? What is going on here?

Comment: `data` is an optional. It's declared as one on the line above. To quote from "A Swift Tour", the first chapter of the book: "You can use if and let together to work with values that might be missing. These values are represented as optionals. An optional value either contains a value or contains nil to indicate that a value is missing. Write a question mark (?) after the type of a value to mark the value as optional."

Answer (score 3):

### Relative path tip:

Instead of doing this:
`NSString("~/file.txt").stringByExpandingTildeInPath`

You can do this:
    `"\(NSHomeDirectory())/file.txt"`

Answer (score 2):

You may find this tool useful to not only read from file in Swift but also parse it simultaneously: https://github.com/shoumikhin/StreamScanner

Just specify the file path and data delimiters like this (see [readme](https://github.com/shoumikhin/StreamScanner) for more options):

```
import StreamScanner

if let input = NSFileHandle(forReadingAtPath: "/file/path")
{
     let scanner = StreamScanner(source: input, delimiters: NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ":\n"))  //separate data by colons and newlines

     while let field: String = scanner.read()
     {
        //use field
     }
}
```

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Using the answer by Atomix, this will work in Swift 4:

```
let location = NSString(string: "~/test.txt").expandingTildeInPath    
let fileContent = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: location, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Swift 2.1, XCode7 to get the location and print the contents of CSV. ( you can create a simple CSV in Text Wrangler)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let location = NSString(string:"/Users/*Myusername*/Documents/myCSVfile.csv")
    let fileContent = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: location as String, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(fileContent)

}
```

Comment: I haven't tested the code but thanks, this helped me decide where to read files directly after starting the app.

Answer (score 1):

`filename` doesn't need to have scheme like `file://`, and can be relative like `../docs/test.txt`.

Remember to `catch` any error thrown, or rethrow. Avoid `try?` to bypass potential problems.

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filename)
let contents = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

```
 let filePath = "/Users/UserName/Desktop/FolderName/FileName.txt"
 let fullPath = NSString(string: filePath).expandingTildeInPath
 do
 {
     let fileContent = try NSString(contentsOfFile: fullPath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
     print(fileContent)
 }
 catch
 {
     print(error)
 }
```