# File not readable from documents folder

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a binary file using few c libraries and saving the file in documents folder of app in iOS. But when i try to read it its not reading. I am using the following code to read.

```
let fileData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe) as Data
```

But this goes always into catch block.

Comment: What is `filePath`? What error do you get?

Comment: Inside your catch-block, type `print(error)`(even though you cannot see a variable named 'error'. In a catch-block, it will work). Tell us the error.

Comment: please check manually if your created files are there in your filepath

Comment: yes the file was not getting created actually due to a code change, thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
do {
    let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: avsset.url)
    print(videoData.count)
} catch let err {
    print("Error:", err)
}
```

you must catch error...

Comment: Since it's specified that it `always goes into catch block`, I assume there is one..

Comment: File was not getting created due to a code change, thanks for pointing out the silly mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You must retrieve your Document folder first and then get the content of document.

```
func readDocument(file:String) -> NSData{
        var vreturn:NSData
        if let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true){
            let dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
            let path = dir.stringByAppendingString(file);
            //reading
            vreturn = (try? NSData(contentsOfFile: path)) ?? NSData()
        }
        return vreturn
    }
```

I'm using this to get String content but it seems to work the same way using NSData. [Simple way to read local file using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846459/simple-way-to-read-local-file-using-swift)