# Swift: Saving NSDictionary to a file, because NSUserDefaults is to slow

Tags: ios, file, swift, save, nsdictionary

I'm using the NSUserDefaults for saving more the 10 big NSDictionarys.

Because the performace is slow, I have the idea to saving the Data into one [or 10 files] instead of using the NSUserDefaults. I need the data just by the starting of the app, so the idea is, saving the data to a file and saving into NSUserDefaults only data I need fast.

I found this solution on stack overflow: 
[Read and write data from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file)

```
let dirs : [String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]
if ((dirs) != nil) {
    let dir = dirs![0]; //documents directory
    let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);
    let text = "some text"

    //writing
    text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil);

    //reading
    let text2 = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
}
```

That works for strings. But when I try to use

NameOfMyDict.writeToFile

I get an error, because Dicts don't have the writeToFile function.

**How can I save Dicts to a file?**

Comment: Maybe you should use CoreData

Answer (score 3):

`NSDictionary` provides a function to save to a file. It is part of `Foundation` framework:

[writeToFile(_ path: String,
      atomically flag: Bool) -> Bool](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/writeToFile:atomically:)

If you use a swift `Dictionary<>`, you may need to cast as a `NSDictionary`. All elements of the dictionary should implement `NSCoding` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize it to JSON and save the JSON string to a file. See [NSJSONSerialization](https://www.google.com.uy/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FFoundation%2FReference%2FNSJSONSerialization_Class%2F&ei=RG98VIqGPMOiNo60gtAM&usg=AFQjCNGhkSTL_lAG22DDMB4z9jLJS3O8bA&bvm=bv.80642063,d.eXY).