# Swift2: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSString'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift development. I just converted existing working code to swift2 while updating Xcode 7 from 6.

```
var err: NSError?
let template = NSString(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &err) as! String
let iframe = template.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("{{VIDEO_ID}}", withString: id, options: NSStringCompareOptions.allZeros, range: nil)
if err != nil {
        return false
}
```

Then,
I got this error message:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSString' with an argument list of type '(contentsOfFile: String, encoding: UInt, error: inout NSError?)'
```

Do you have any idea? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Swift native type String. Also you need to implement Swift 2.0 do try catch error handling. Try like this:

```
let template = try! String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let iframe = template.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("{{VIDEO_ID}}", withString: id, options: [], range: nil)
```

If you would like to handle the error:

```
do {
    let template = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let iframe = template.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("{{VIDEO_ID}}", withString: id, options: [], range: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: I haven't done much with Swift 2.0 yet. Can you elaborate on your answer to explain how the error parameter of the `String(contentsOfFile:encoding:error:)` method gets dropped out of the call and passed to the catch? The docs still only show the form of the initializer with the error parameter included.

Comment: @DuncanC all you need to do is to remove the last parameter(error) and add try in front of the method, and catch the error as NSError. If you dont want to handle the error just use try!

Comment: I found a [**link on big nerd ranch**](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/error-handling-in-swift-2/)  that explains it pretty well. Does the method definition have to be rewritten in the new form with the "throws" qualifier for this to work? And is it just that the docs are behind? The Xcode docs on `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:` don't even show a Swift version of the method, so it's a bit hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: @DuncanC it is really easy, you will get used to it really fast. You should take a look at guard also

Comment: @DuncanC https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: My questions are specifically about the method signatures of the methods that you can use this with. Do they have to have the catch qualifier before they work?

Comment: I think only the asynchronous methods you dont use this

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Swift 2's ["do-try-catch" syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) for handling the error:

```
do {
    let template = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    // Use the template
} catch let error as NSError {
    // Handle the error
}
```

Definitely read the docs on this as it shows a few other ways of handling errors - for example `try?` will give you an optional in the case of any error, and `try!` will block error propagation (though you'll get a runtime error if an error *does* occur).

Comment: Thanks. I'm learning Swift2 from understanding the existing codes. So, it will take some time. Thanks again for your valuable suggestion.