# Send Label result to a file

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have a simple calculator which display the results in a label, I want to export the results to a pdf, email, or text file. Any clue how could I make it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the value of your UILabel.text. After that saving it to a file should be pretty easy.

```
let file = "file.txt"

if let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String] {
    let dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
    let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);
    let text = myLabel.text

//writing
text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil);
```

Copied the code from this [answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24098149/1891327)

Comment: Just what I need :) Thank you iosDev82 :)

Comment: @Manolo Glad to be of help. Have a great day. :)