# Swift write to file (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

How can I write to an xml document in Swift? I have this code:

```
let content = "<tag>Example</tag>"
var error: NSError?
content.writeToFile(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("my_file", ofType: "xml")!, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
```

But this does not update the file in my Xcode project or on the device. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Does the error have any content?

Comment: As far as I know, bundles are read-only. You need to use a path in your app's doc or tmp folder.

Comment: `error.localizedDescription` is nil

Comment: @dasblinkenlight how can I do this?

Comment: @GabrielJones [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24098149/335858) has an example.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight And this would apply to iOS directories as well?

Comment: Yes. Usually you’d use NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask instead of .AllDomainsMask, but either should work.

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon Is there a way I could replace the whole document with new content?

Comment: Should be happening already—IIRC you have to do some additional work to append to a file instead of just overwriting it. Is that not what you’re seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To collect all the fragments provided in comments into one place:

The app bundle is read-only on iOS. You can't save to it. It isn't forced to be read-only on Mac OS, but you should still treat it as such. As a result of this difference, code that modifies the app bundle may work on the simulator, but fail on an actual device.

You should save your contents to a file in the user's documents directory or one of the other sandbox directories. That code might look like this:

```
let docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( 
  NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,
  NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask,
  true)[0] as! NSString
let filePath = docsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("myfile")
let content = "<tag>Example</tag>"
var error: NSError?
content.writeToFile(filePath, 
  ofType: "xml", 
  atomically: true, 
  encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, 
  error: &error)
```

Then you should add error-checking that checks the bool result of the writeToFile command. If the result is false, check the error to see what went wrong.

Note that there is built-in support in iOS for reading XML, and quite a few third party libraries for saving collections of objects in XML format. You should take a look at NSXMLParser for reading. I can't really recommend one of the XML writing libraries over the others.

If you aren't wedded to XML, you might take a look at JSON. It's more compact, easier to write, easier to read, less memory-intensive, and there is built-in system support for both reading and writing Cocoa data structures from/to JSON files.