# Swift Array size limit and Xcode compile limits

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

I have extracted OSX English language dictionary and want to use it in my Swift iPhone app. It has about 236,000 words which I have added to a swift string array.

When I try to run the build, it takes a long time to compile and then throws `Segmentation Fault 11`

Is this because the array is too big?

Am I going the correct path trying to add english dictionary in my project?

Comment: Can you post your code here? Especially the for loop part

Comment: Is the English dictionary part of your source code or do you add it as a resource and read it from the file system?

Comment: An average word in English has 7 characters. 236K words take 1.5MB. That's not too big, even on iOS devices.

Comment: I havn't even implemented a for loop yet. I am just declaring the array with 236,000 word strings in it. It is in the swift file not a separate resource file.

Comment: The swift file is about 2.5MB

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using a different way. For example a C file with an array of char*.

Comment: I only know swift. What would be the equivalent of 'c file with char' in swift?

Comment: You don't have to use C. Please find the required information in this posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file

Comment: Save your dictionary as a delimited text file and then load it using `String.stringWithContentsOfFile(...)` and then split the string up using `split(myString) { $0 == <some delimeter> }`

Comment: @GoatlinTheMachine: But then would it not result in the same huge array of string with 236,000 entries in the memory, which is causing the issue right now?

Comment: You might be better using `CoreData` or some sort of DB framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by adding the actual dictionary text file into my xcode project. then utilize below code to fill words from the file to an array. it was pretty fast.

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("dict2", ofType: "txt")
let dico = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
let dict = dico!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem @Kashif is "dict2" a supporting file "dict2.txt"?

Comment: I just dragged dict2.txt into my project and made sure it target was selected

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not store this as a single string. There are more efficient data structures that you can use, such as a `trie`. You should also consider not loading the entire content into memory at one point but be able to navigate it from the filesystem.

Comment: As I answered myself, I was able to solve the issue but looping through array still takes some 0.2 sec or so which is slow for the purpose of my app. I like the trie idea but this concept is new to me and I do not know how to implement it in SWIFT. Will I need an additional framework or extension to accomplish it?