# config files - in which folder and where in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, file-management

I'm porting my android app to iOS. In android I have the asset folder I can manage through the studio and where all my config files reside.

Where should reside my txt config files in Xcode: Supporting files, Poducts, xcassets, ...?

What should I use to open/read the files? Should I use the following constants?

```
   let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
   let currDir = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
```

is there a good article/tuto you recommend to read?

many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a cross-platform way of doing things, and as such won't answer your question directly, but if you wanted to do things "the Apple way", see this: http://www.myswiftjourney.me/2014/10/01/simple-persistent-storage-using-nsuserdefaults/

You shouldn't need to worry about raw file access if you're only saving config values.

Comment: I might not have been clear in my request. Persistent storage between restart is interesting but at the moment I need to take care about the initialization first. For example one the thing that does my app is showing a list of author and extract a short display of the novel. Ex: London, Poe, Wilde, etc... And this config shows the text associated that I need to display. So where do I put all of that in Xcode (config file + text of the novel)? How do I open it programmatically?

Comment: examples of raw reading and writing to files can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file