# persist dictionary to file and read it back

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning Swift. I have created an dictionary:

```
var myDict = Dictionary<String, String>()
myDict["AAA"] = "aaa"
myDict["BBB"] = "bbb"
```

Now I want to persist this dictionary to a file. I get a file path under documents:

```
let docDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).last as? String

let filePath = docDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("MyFile.txt")
```

Until here, I don't know how to store `myDict` to the file. And also how to read the `myDict` back from file. Could someone please guide me through please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSMutableDictionary

```
    private var myDict: NSMutableDictionary!
```

For writing to user defaults:

```
    let def:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
    def.setObject(myDict, forKey: "YOUR_KEY");
    def.synchronize();
```

For writing to file:

```
var text:String = ""
for (key, value) in myDict {
    text += "\(key as! String)=\(value as! String)\n"
}

do {
    try text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
catch {/* error handling here */}
```

For reading:

```
    let def:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
    let ur:NSDictionary? = def.objectForKey("YOUR_KEY") as? NSDictionary;
    if(ur == nil) {
        myDict = NSMutableDictionary();
        myDict.setValue("aaa", forKey:"AAA");
        myDict.setValue("bbb", forKey:"BBB");
    }
    else{
        myDict = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: ur!)
    }
```

Comment: How to create an empty `NSMutableDictionary` in swift? I tried `var myDict : NSMutableDictionary = [String: String]()` But I got error `[String: String] is not convertible to NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: Besides, I would like to write the dictionary to a file, I don't want to set to NSUserDefaults

Comment: For writing text to file, you can use link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826). Before writing you have to format text with key-value pairs and parse key-value pairs for reading. To create instance use var myDict: NSMutableDictionary  = NSMutableDictionary();