# how to create a text file in swift 2

Tags: swift2

I wonder how I can create a .txt file in a folder in Application Support. How can I do?

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
fileManager.createFileAtPath(/*how to create a text file in Application Support > some folder?*/)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read and write data from text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//  create a folder in Application Support
var path = String()

let applicationSupportDirectory = NSSearchPathDirectory.ApplicationSupportDirectory
let nsUserDomainMask = NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( applicationSupportDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true )
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

path = paths[0] + "/" + folderNameYouWant

//  check if the folder already exists
if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath( path ) == false
{
    _ = try? fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath( path,
                   withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                                    attributes: nil )
}

//  prepare content and write to file
let content = "text file content"

_ = try? content.writeToFile( path,
                  atomically: true,
                    encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding )
```