# How do you use the function createFile?

Tags: swift

I found this declaration in Apple's API reference but I'm not sure how to use it.

```
func createFile(atPath path: String, contents data: Data?, attributes attr: [String : Any]? = nil) -> Bool
```

When I start typing `createFile`, there is no auto-complete that resembles this declaration either.

My path is a directory on my computer (not including the file's name), and the data is a string.

Comment: I have seen that question. It doesn't create a new file. It just writes to an existing one? Edit: Oh that is not the one I was thinking. I will try that one.

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720817/how-to-create-a-text-file-in-swift-2

Comment: It does not work. I have successful code that writes to an existing file. I just need to create a new one. Can I not use the `createFile` function to make one?

Comment: is it iOS ? I mean iphone application?

Comment: Do you mean what I am creating? Yes it is an iPhone application.

Comment: You have to start typing `createFile` on an instance of `FileManager`.

Comment: Note that now the `attributes` is of type `[FileAttributeKey: Any]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine on my machine. You probably just aren't using a FileManager object:

[image]

Comment: You are right thank you. And I am just using the simulator.

Comment: No offence to you or professionals, but can I just not play around?

Comment: @matt did you try it? I am able to access even the root directory of my mac .. I am able to create there a file and read and write to/from it running  an iOS application in the simulator. By the way, there are no words about ios or iPhone in the question ... The same syntax I use at macOS ...