# writeToFile is working on simulator and not working on device using ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
    if let filepath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(“abc”, ofType: "txt")

    {
        var test_string=“abcd”
        let fileContent:NSData= test_string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        fileContent.writeToFile(filepath, atomically: true)
        let contents = try NSString(contentsOfFile: filepath, usedEncoding: nil) as String
        print("file content  :  "+contents)
    }
    catch
    {
        self.view.makeToast("write to file error")
    }
```

Comment: You can't write to the bundle folder

Comment: If you need a place to write your string you can use the documents, preferences or application support folder

Comment: @Leo Dabus . how can i use documents, preferences or application support folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26557965/2303865

Comment: Thanks a lot... its working fine...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Read and write data from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file).

I think your problem is the path, because a simulator folder can be any where but for device no, it is better to save the file inside the folder of your apps itself.

And if you are writing text, you can just write `try test_string.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

Comment: am saving  the file inside the folder of my apps itself.

Comment: have you check the path you writing to your device? It's something like this **/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1AS7BED8-FF5F-48B1-AWE9-1EEF2EE3E500/Documents/abc.txt**. I think you're saving it inside your project bundle

Comment: my file path    :    "/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7B0B3136-B2F5-4A4A-B989-04FE5FDA5979/fileSwift.app/abc.txt"    .   How can i change to    "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/..."

Comment: Im using the method in the link above for my apps and it does work for both simulator and device. However, when i tried your code the filepath is a nil. I think the code i learnt is easy to use and understand

Comment: i created abc.txt file inside my app folder and do the code i wrote above. can u give me detail code for create , read  and write of text file

Comment: I had attached actually in the post
[this is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Thanks a lot.....its working fine..:)                                                             let documentDirectoryURL = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
                
   // create the destination url for the text file to be saved
    let fileDestinationUrl = documentDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("abc.txt")                              try text.writeToURL(fileDestinationUrl, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

Comment: its okay haha, I had actually added the link in the post. Just maybe the link color is not that obvious. mark as answer please if dont mind :)