# iOS Swift: tblSearchResults unresolved identifier and can not invoke String (contentsOfFile...)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a few issues in building a search bar for searching a list of work types for a project I am building. I am getting a lot of red exclamation points saying "tblSearchResults" is an unresolved identifier.

Here is a the project source code where the issue is occurring.

```
    func WorkTypeSearchable() {

    let pathToFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("work", ofType: "txt")

    if let path = pathToFile {

        let workString = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding:
NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!

        let WorkTypeSearchable = workString.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")

        tblSearchResults.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Can you explain why I would be getting an error as an unresolved identifier, as well as well an error with my string for "workString = String(code)...

I am using all the appropriate classes as seen here:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource,
UIPickerViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,
UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
```

Note that I am also using a picker later in the program.

Comment: Are you using Swift 2? (Xcode 7.x) Also, could you paste the part where you declare `tblSearchResults`?

Comment: yes, would that make the difference in code failure?

Comment: For the String line, yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An unresolved identifier error indicates that Xcode cannot find where you defined `tblSearchResults`. Did you connect an IBOutlet and initialize the delegate? Implementing the delegate alone will not cause `tblSearchResults` to point to the UITableView you want.

To create an IBOutlet, open the Assistant Editor, then Control-Drag from the UITableView to just below your class declaration, and change the type to Outlet and the name to `tblSearchResults`. Then, you will probably also want to initialize the delegate and dataSource in the `viewDidLoad()`, like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tblSearchResults: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tblSearchResults.delegate = self
        tblSearchResults.dataSource = self
        //Insert other initialization code here
    }
}
```

### String Init: Swift 1 vs. Swift 2

You mentioned that you are using Swift 2, which no longer uses the [String initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826) method you used in your code. There are two differences:

1. You must use NSString instead of String
2. You must use a try statement

Try this: (please note that it is unsafe, the app will crash if the file can't be read)

```
let text2 = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: This helped immensely. I suppose I should make sure the resources I use in the future are for the most current version of Swift.

Comment: Good idea. In addition to major features like error handling, several minor things were changed, which can get annoying if you're looking at Swift 1 code. Glad I could help!