# Issues writing to file in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, file-io, swift2

I am currently both reading and writing from a file in swift, and the reading works fine, while the writing seems to be doing nothing.  Here is what I am using to read:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "txt")
let returnString = try? String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

and here is what I am trying to use to write:

```
let text = "hi mom"
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "txt")
do{
    try text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);
}
catch{
    print("nope")
}
```

It is not throwing an error, but also not changing the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add/modify anything located inside the resources folder (bundled with your app). You can save it to the documents directory.

Comment: If you need a reference to do so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file/26557965#26557965