# Write to local html file in Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, bundle

I have some html code that I have receive from json. Now I have to write this html code to html document that is in my project and than show it in webView. How can I write my HTML code to my html file in my project.

Here is in my content variable I have HTML code.

```
func getArticles() {
    //let id = "1018"
    let url = "http://www.salemkz.kz/inc/API/getArticles.php?idArticle=170"
    print(url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            let jsons = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]
            if let results = jsons["result"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                //print("got Result", results)
                for result in results {
                    let content = result["content"] as? String
                    print(content!)
                }

            }

        }
        }.resume()

}
```

And I have to write this code to this html file (named "articles-1.html") : 
[image]

How to do this ???

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Comment: Already Done !   @maddy

Comment: you want to write html file or showing in webview ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file usi this and just set file extention .htm with .txt

Comment: @BHAVIK PANCHAL Already tried this don't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can generate this document manually. Not an elegant solution, but will work. Try this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

var generatedHtml : String?
var receivedContent: String? = ""

func getArticles() {
        //let id = "1018"
        let url = "http://www.salemkz.kz/inc/API/getArticles.php?idArticle=170"

        print(url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { [weak self]
            (data, response, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            else {
                let jsons = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]
                if let results = jsons["result"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    //print("got Result", results)
                    for result in results {
                        let content = result["content"] as? String
                        if (content != nil) {
                            self?.receivedContent?.append(content!)
                        }
                        print(content!)
                    }
                    self?.generatedHtml = self?.generateString()
                    if ((self?.generatedHtml) != nil) {
                        self?.webView.loadHTMLString((self?.generatedHtml!)!, baseURL: nil)
                    }
                }

            }
            }.resume()
    }

func generateString() -> String? {
        var resultString: String?

        let firstString = "<DOCTYPE HTML> \r <html lang=\"en\" \r <head> \r <meta charset = \"utf-8\"> \r </head> \r <body>"
        let endString = "</body> \r </html>";
        resultString = firstString + self.receivedContent! + endString;

        return resultString
    }
```

webView here is a view, where you want to display this html. If you want to save the html to file, you can also do this, just modify code a bit. (Use String. writeToFile method)