# How to append or add multiple items to an array in Swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Here is what I want to archive:

I have a couple of names, let's say it 100 names. These names are listed in a text file or an excel file. I would like to add those names to an array, when I tap a button.

```
var namesPool: [String] = []
```

[image]

But I have no ideas how to get it work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: There is many things to do: Add the file in your ressources, parse the file and put the result in an array 'nameArray', create UI with a button, add an action on this button to copy a name from your nameArray to your namePool... Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Y.Bonafons Thanks for all the input, sir. I get it work with Ayman’s help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First : add the text file into the project.

Second: make sure it's present in Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.

```
 func getNames(fileName: String) -> [String]?
 {
     guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "txt") else
     {
         return nil
     }

     do
     {
         let content = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            return content.components(separatedBy: "\n")
     }
     catch _ as NSError
     {
         return nil
     }
 }
```

Usage:

```
let namesPool = getNames(fileName:"names")
```

Comment: Thanks, Ayman. That's what I need. But if I didn't have the text file in the project, I mean how can I add a text file when I tap a button, after the project was built as an app? Any ideas you can share with me?

Comment: rather than reading the file from the bundle, read it from the the download directory path.

Comment: Thanks a lot，really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to read the text from your file. There is a good example on how to do this here: [Read and write data from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file)

The second step is to convert the output String to an array. Since every name is on one line, you can separate each value by the `\n` newline character.

```
let names = fileNames.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for all the input, sir.