# IOS: Export a file created by a mobile application (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a mobile application (IOS with Swift), which creates a text file.

My question is, how do I store this file, so I can maybe send it to my computer or if I plugged in the device drag and drop it on to the computer.

So I actually want to create a file on a mobile device and use this file in a different project running on the computer.

Comment: This will be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file

Comment: Not rly, I found the same. Maybe my question is just to simple and I have no idea. But lets assume my IOS application now writes a file. Then I plug the device back into the computer and now I want to extract this file on to the computer. So i can see all the informations on that file or load it with a different application. How can I get this file?