# How To Read From File Swift

Tags: swift

```
func writeToFile(content: String, fileName: String) {

    let contentToAppend = content+"\n"
    let filePath = NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/" + fileName

    //Check if file exists
    if let fileHandle = NSFileHandle(forWritingAtPath: filePath) {
        //Append to file
        fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
        fileHandle.writeData(contentToAppend.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    }
    else {
        //Create new file
        do {
            try contentToAppend.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        } catch {
            print("Error creating \(filePath)")
        }
    }
}
```

I have that code which allows me to call this function and it writes to a file. Now im stuck as to how can I read this File. I'd like to have this display the files contents inside a multi line Text box. Can someone help me with a Read function for this code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-a-string-from-text-file

Comment: Consider that `NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/"` does not work if the app is sandboxed. There are convenience methods in `FileManager` to get the standard directories.

Comment: @vadian The answers in the duplicate show the proper way to get the Documents folder.