# How do I use String(contentsOfFile: ) in Swift?

Tags: swift

**Edit:** I do not believe this question is a duplicate of [Read and write a String from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-a-string-from-text-file). I linked **that exact question** in this one explaining that it did not work!

I want to be able to read a `.txt` file I am including within my `Xcode` project in an `iOS` app. I have the following code:

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
override func sceneDidLoad() {
        let path = bundle.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "txt")
        let string = try String(contentsOfFile: path!) else throw Error
        }
```

All the lines up until `let string = ...` are fine. However, everything I have found in questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-a-string-from-text-file) are unable to read the `data.txt` file as they are incorrect/outdated syntax.

How do I read from it?

**Edit:** I've got the `let string` to be this:

```
do {
        let string = try String(contentsOfFile: path!)
        print(string) // prints the content of data.txt
    }
catch {
    throw Error
}
```

But I still have two errors:

*Thrown expression type 'Error.Protocol' does not conform to 'Error'*

and

*Error is not handled because the enclosing function is not declared 'throws'*

How do I fix the errors?

Comment: That’s not valid Swift syntax. You should read the [Error Handling](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html) chapter in the Swift book.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Yes, the syntax is outdated, but I'm not sure what the correct syntax is. I'll look at what you sent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to handle the possible error thrown by encapsulating the throwable function in a `do-catch` block. In the `catch` block you shouldn't throw an error, but rather parse the error thrown and decide what to do with it.

```
let path = bundle.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "txt")!
do {
    let string = try String(contentsOfFile: path)
} catch {
    print(error)
    // Handle the error
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. This is my first time using `do` statements, thanks for the help.

Comment: You should use URL instead of Strings (path). `let fileURL = bundle.for(forResource: "data", withExtension: "txt")!` and then `let string = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)`. If you need the path for any reason you can always get the URL path property `fileURL.path`
 `