# How to output NSTextView Content to Textfile

Tags: xcode, macos, swift4.2

I have the following Code and want to Export the Result of 
`self.logger.string += line`
to a File. How to do?

```
func syncShellExec(path: String, args: [String] = []) {
    //let script             = [path!]
    let process            = Process()
    process.launchPath     = "/bin/bash"
    process.arguments      = [path] + args
    let outputPipe         = Pipe()
    let filelHandler       = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading
    process.standardOutput = outputPipe

    filelHandler.readabilityHandler = { pipe in
        let data = pipe.availableData
        if let line = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            // Update your view with the new text here
            // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.logger.string += line
            }
        } else {
            print("Error decoding data: \(data.base64EncodedString())")
        }
    }

    process.launch()
    process.waitUntilExit()
    filelHandler.readabilityHandler = nil
    //self.loggerScroll.flashScrollers()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below (modified and [stolen from this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24098149/981049)):

```
let file = "file.txt" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it

let text = self.logger.string  //the text we'll write

// we'll write the file in the user's documents directory
if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

    let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

    //writing
    do {
        try text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
    }
    catch {/* error handling here */}
}
```