# Swift: record touch force, size, duration

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitouch

For a data analysis project, I want to track the measurements for touch force, size and duration in a log-file for a simple app (I use the [Foodtracker app](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/swift/downloads/09_PersistData.zip) from the Apple Documentation Website).

I know that I can get the [force](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618110-force), [size](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618106-majorradius) and [duration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618144-timestamp) from UITouch. But

1. how do I access UITouch to get these measurements?
2. and how do I write these measurements into a log-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. How do I access UITouch to get these measurements?

You'll have to override the touch handlers in your view controller.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    let touch = touches.first!
    print("\(touch.force)")
    print("\(touch.majorRadius)")
    print("\(touch.timestamp)")
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    let touch = touches.first!
    print("\(touch.force)")
    print("\(touch.majorRadius)")
    print("\(touch.timestamp)")
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
    let touch = touches.first!
    print("\(touch.force)")
    print("\(touch.majorRadius)")
    print("\(touch.timestamp)")
}
```

#### 2. How do I write these measurements into a log-file?

For that checkout this post: [Read and write a String from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24098149/1752496)

Comment: don't forget to call super when overriding those methods `super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)`

Comment: Right. Even though it's only necessary if the view controller inherits from a class that is not `UIViewController` directly and also uses these methods.

Comment: Thanks! I works quite well, but not when I click on UIButtons. I also created and used a subclass of UIButtons and included the functions from above, but that did not work. What am I missing?

Comment: Well for that, please checkout this thread https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/91263