# Reading Contents of File Not Working with FileManager

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift.

I am trying to write a simple app that just reads a file and converts its contents to a string. I am using FileManager and the example given here for Swift 4: [Read and write a String from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-a-string-from-text-file)

It's not working though. The issue, I am assuming, is that I am giving the wrong URL to the `String(contentsOf: URL)` method. The exact error thrown is that it couldn't open the file because it doesn't exist.

Below is my `ViewController.swift` code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testText: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let test = directoryContents()
        do {
            let text = try String(contentsOf: test)
            testText.text! = text
        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

func directoryContents() -> URL {
    var dirContents: URL!
    dirContents = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    dirContents = dirContents.appendingPathComponent("testdata.txt")
    return dirContents
}
```

The rest of the app files are generic Single View App files. I would include an image of the sidebar, but the question editor was throwing an error when I tried to upload it. Basically, it looks like:

```
testingData/
 testingData/
  TestData/
   testdata.txt
  AppDelegate.swift
  ViewController.swfit
  Main.storyboard
  Assets.xcassets
  LaunchScreen.storyboard
  Info.plist
 Products/
  testingData.app
```

The `Main.storyboard` has a `TextView` added to it that is the `testText` in my `ViewController`. The file I am trying to read in is the `testdata.txt`, which is a text file containing the text `1,2,3,4,5,6` and nothing else. It is a member of the `testingData` app.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. If this is answered somewhere else on here, kindly point me in that direction and I'll close this out.

Comment: You should include txt file to the bundle via build settings at project setting. And then use Bundle api to get a path to the file. For example, [Bundle.url...](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is in the application bundle you have to use the API of `Bundle`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let test = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"testdata", withExtension: "txt")!
    do {
        let text = try String(contentsOf: test)
        testText.text! = text
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

and delete `directoryContents()`